# How to achieve a "contact" button on incoming call screen

Tags: ios, ios9, telephony, incoming-call

Recently I installed an app named "Ringo" What they are doing is a different thing. But I got amazed by seeing a "contact" button when they call your phone. Please see attached screenshot.

They basically create a contact in my address book with an image and when they call my phone number using one of added number I got this screen, This screen is different then usual contact incoming call screen. If I set an image for a contact I get a full screen image of that contact when they call me. Name is center aligned and there is no button to go to that contact.

I am looking to achieve the same thing. Is this some kind of setting when adding the contact in address book? or this is some kind of trick.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two types of images that can be associated with a contact:

- a "large" image, that can only be set on the device itself, and is supposedly not synced via iCloud. Programmatically, this would be manipulated via `ABPersonSetImageData`
- smaller "photo" and "logo" images, which may be included in a vCard (see `PHOTO` and `LOGO` in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties).

I believe the former is displayed full screen, while the latter (or maybe only one of the two) is displayed as the smaller icon top right.

I haven't found a direct way to set those, but you may be able to generate a vCard and pass it to `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation`. You'll have to include either an URL or a base-64 representation of the image.

Alternatively, it may be just based on the size of the picture, though I don't know what the exact threshold would be, taking into account Retina sizes etc.

Comment: But this is not just about the image size. That image acts as a button and when tapped open the contact detail page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as long as the image is displayed top right instead of full screen, it will act as a link to the contact. You can see how they do it by exporting the contact and checking the vCard, it contains a `PHOTO` property provided as a JPEG in base64 encoding.

Comment: FYI, the image is a 276 x 276 JPEG.